# Cast enum to int and insert that int value from another table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am Converting my *Enum* datatype to *Integer* and Also Want to Insert that perticular id to int value which in another table.

*Enum* Type in **product_mst**

```
measurement_unit: Enum('pair','piece') and Default value is 'pair'
```

When i will convert it to integer its id should be lookup in another table.

Another Table that is **measurement_unit_mst**

```
measurement_unit_id | unit_name |
        5              pair
        8              piece
```

It should be 5 for pair and also 8 for piece, when i convert it to *integer*.

Normally, it takes 1 and 2 for 'pair' and 'piece' that i don't want it.

I applied below three query which working for me.

```
ALTER TABLE `product_mst` CHANGE `measurement_unit` `measurement_unit` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0';
UPDATE product_mst set measurement_unit=5 where measurement_unit=1;
UPDATE product_mst set measurement_unit=8 where measurement_unit=2;
```

Any other Better option for this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If your data table is the central part in your design, then it might be better to initalize the enum with the corresponding numbers of the table so you can omit the conversion:

```
abstract class MeasurementUnit
{
    const pair = 5;
    const piece = 8;
    // etc.
}
```

Access like

```
$pair = MeasurementUnit::pair;
```

Comment: But in future, if pair and piece value changed then what can i do..how i maintain repeatedly ?

Comment: @Farhanshaikh When the table is subject to change, then revise your design by reading the table at application start and dynamically assign ids to your MeasurementUnit. Having to manage separate lists (in table and in code) (= duplication) is bad design nevertheless.

Comment: **measurement_mst** table also contain another units with pair and piece. and it will be user define value.User can CRUD **meaurement_mst** data. it was only two value in product_mst that was enum, but now it will be multiple ids.